# angular notification not showing native popup asking permission

Tags: angular, push-notification

I am using Angular 8 for a pwa. I added relevant modules to enable web notification. On requesting permission for notification, it is expected to show a native popup, clicking on which give us the endpoint details. But this popup is not showing and the promise is never resolved.

I am using an express server with web-push to send notification. This server serves the angular app also. I have seen these issues, [freeze issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29067) , [pushManager issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30552), but couldn't find a solution. I have done prod build of angular app.

I debugged the service-worker.js file(from node_moduels/@angular/service-worker), and found that

```js
this.pushManager = this.sw.registration.pipe(map((/**
   * @param {?} registration
   * @return {?}
   */
   registration => registration.pushManager)));
```

this push manager observable is used later to get endpoint data, but the execution never goes further into the pipeline.
browser support service worker and rest of the app is working without much issues.

This  is the code I use which is straight from the docs.

```js
init() {
    this.push.requestSubscription({ serverPublicKey: <my pub key> })
    .then(
      (success) => {
        console.log(success);
        this.subscriptionDetails = success;
        this.http.post('http://localhost:9020/<sub-endpoint>', success).subscribe(() => {
          this.push.messages.subscribe(message => console.log(message));
        });
      },
      (error) => console.error(error)
    ).catch(err => console.error('requestSubscription Error: ',err));
  }
```

Neither the error nor the success got consoled, promise never resolved and the native popups asking user permission never shown. I have checked the chrome settings to see if permission already there and its not.

Expects the code to show a native popup asking user permission for notification. Giving permission should resolve the promise and yield the endpoint data.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The funny thing is that the popup that asks for the permission shows in Firefox, but not in chrome and safari. I'm been struggling with this for a day now. And I had it working with an older version of angular CLI and Angular. When I updated everything to the latest versions, it stopped working out of the box in chrome and safari. And just tested it in Opera and it seems to work in Opera. So it's a webkit problem I guess.

Comment: Hi, any news on this issue? Did you solved it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like this:

```
.then(sub => register(sub))
.catch(err => console.error('requestSubscription Error: ',err));

register(success){
    this.subscriptionDetails = success;
    this.http.post('http://localhost:9020/<sub-endpoint>', success).subscribe(() => {
      this.push.messages.subscribe(message => console.log(message));
    });
}
```

Also you need to `ng build --prod` for the service worker to function properly.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. I am taking production build and having no luck with this.